# connecting to phpMyAdmin database with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've made a database using phpMyAdmin , now I want to make a register form for my site where peaple can register .I know how to work with input tags in HTML and I know how to insert data into a database but my problem is that I don't know how I can connect to the database that is already made in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The database is a *MySQL* database, not a *phpMyAdmin* database. phpMyAdmin is only PHP code that connects to the DB.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_database('db_name') or die (mysql_error());

// now you are connected
```

Comment: mysql_connect(),mysql_select_database() have been deprecated. Here are the new functions: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 3):

Connect to MySQL

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'username';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Also mysqli_connect() function to open a new connection to the MySQL server.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname); 

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a user, a host the user is allowed to talk to MySQL by using (e.g. localhost), grant that user adequate permissions to do what they need with the database .. and presto.

The user will need basic [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) privileges to start, that's sufficient to store data received from a form. The rest of the permissions are self explanatory, i.e. permission to alter tables, etc. Give the user no more, no less power than it needs to do its work.

Comment: http://z.about.com/d/musiced/1/0/-/8/viola.jpg
What permissions does one need to do what they need to with the viola?

Comment: @byronh: The viola is used to keep sleepy stack overflow users from making typographical errors :)

Answer (score 0):

> This (mysql_connect, mysql_...) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension should be used. 
> (ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

- Object Oriented:

  ```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password");
  $mysqli->select_db("db");
  ```
- Procedural:

  ```
  $link = mysqli_connect("host","user","password") or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
  mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new mysqli('Server_Name', 'Name', 'password', 'database_name');
```

Comment: please share some explanation about how this code solve the problem

Comment: This code only for the connection with the database